# How a for loop should wait until a function inside it finish its execution in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array `$scope.requisition` that has three elements inside it and, for each element, I'm performing some task(api call and fetching some data), but the output I'm  getting is "item1" "item1" "item1" "item2" "item2" "item2" which is not synchronous. What I want is for the loop to wait for the api to fetch the data and then go for the next execution which is not happening.

The output expected is:

- 1st execution("item1" "item2")
- 2nd execution("item1" "item2")
- 3rd execution("item1" "item2")

```
for(var index in $scope.requisition){
    var tableName = JSON.parse($scope.requisition[index].applyFormConfig).table;
    console.log("item1 "+JSON.stringify($scope.requisition[index]));

    privateMetadata.getCustomFieldNames({entityName:tableName}).$promise.then(function(results) {
        $scope.target.tableFields = normalizeObjects(results);
        console.log("item2 "+JSON.parse($scope.requisition[index].applyFormConfig).items);
        angular.forEach(JSON.parse($scope.requisition[index].applyFormConfig).items,function(item){
            var mappedJsonObj = getObjectByIdFromArray(item.id, $scope.target.tableFields);
        });
    });
};
```

I'm new to this framework so I don't know how to do this.

Comment: the concept of promises itself is asynchronous, you should reconsider your algorithm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait for each promise to be done after continuing loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47247203/wait-for-each-promise-to-be-done-after-continuing-loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promises are asynchronous, but you can work around this by creating a counter variable and putting your promise in a function that recursively calls itself when successful, then incrementing the counter until the last index has been reached.
Snippet:

```
var index = 0;
$scope.myFunction = function(){
    var tableName = JSON.parse($scope.requisition[index].applyFormConfig).table;
    console.log("item1 "+JSON.stringify($scope.requisition[index]));

    privateMetadata.getCustomFieldNames({entityName:tableName}).$promise.then(function(results) {
        $scope.target.tableFields = normalizeObjects(results);
        console.log("item2 "+JSON.parse($scope.requisition[index].applyFormConfig).items);
        angular.forEach(JSON.parse($scope.requisition[index].applyFormConfig).items,function(item){
            var mappedJsonObj = getObjectByIdFromArray(item.id, $scope.target.tableFields);
        });
        if(index!=$scope.requisition.length - 1){
            index++;
            $scope.myFunction();
        }
    });
}
```